# Erro de CORS ao tentar autenticar uma API em localhost

Tags: angularjs, apache, cors

Estou tentando acessar minha API que está em localhost. Porém, ao tentar acessa-la, me deparo com o seguinte erro:

> Failed to load http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *', but only one is allowed. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1' is therefore not allowed access.

Será necessário configurar algo em particular no meu apache ou falha de codificação no meu app-config.js(estou utilizando angularJs) ?

app-config:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';
   app.constant('AppConfig', {
    AppTitle: 'testeBase',
   ApiUrl: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/'
  });
})();
```

Comment: Estou utilizando o xampp. Onde posso encontrar esse código?

Comment: Sua API, foi desenvolvida em qual linguagem? Está utilizando algum framework específico?

Comment: Ai ta dizendo que o header está definido duas vezes. Posta o código do arquivo da api que você está acessando e talvez o arquivo .htaccess